# Surprise! the shell suggests command line switches

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I noticed that the bash shell can suggest command line switches for your command.

Just type your command, a dash (-) and type tab. The shell will show you available switches.

For example, try:

```
andy@andyx:~$ java -
```

and press tab - Surprise!

[image: Screenshot]

The question is:

**How do I interface with this feature. I.e., if I write a program that is to be run from the console, what's the API to tell the shell what switches are available?**

Comment: Hm... my bash seams to be lacking this feature. Do I need to enable it somehow?

Comment: It only works if a command is set up to use it in /etc/bash_completion.d  (see MrX answer below.)  I tried it too, with ls, and it didn't work, but looking in that dir I see that yast2 has a 100 line completion script on one of our systems.    Lotta work to set this up!

Might be nice to do if you are writing a unix tool that a lot of people are going to use, but not for personal work.

Use --help with gnu utilities, instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have discovered Bash's [programmable completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion) feature.

Answer (score 6):

See:

```
$ man bash
```

In particular, the section entitled "READLINE" and subsection "Programmable Completion"

Answer (score 5):

FYI: In Ubuntu and/or Debian the scripts are at /etc/bash_completion.d/