# How to enable tab-completion of command line switches in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

With `bash`, I can complete a command with TAB. Normally, it should also complete the command line switches: e.g. when I typed:

```
java -
```

it should show me the possibilities.  It does not. How can I enable this preview?

See also [Surprise! the shell suggests command line switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776071)

Comment: How do I add functionality to my command line scripts, so they too can offer auto completion for commands? (I have googled, but only get stuff about how to use it, and completion via history file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [Extended Bash Completion](http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#completion)

Answer (score 5):

You need to have `bash_completion` installed and then just add `. /etc/bash_completion` to your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Don't know if the name changed but I needed to install `bash-completion` (with the dash), see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/86375/apt-get-autocomplete-package-name-is-broken

Answer (score 4):

Related: [Surprise! the shell suggests command line switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776071/surprise-the-shell-suggests-command-line-switches)

In the answers to that question there were several links to documentation. You might find what you look for there.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what Linux flavor you're using, you may want to add a package.  For Fedora and related distributions, you need to add the separate package `bash-completion` to get this to work.  I wouldn't be surprised if other distributions had this packaged as an optional 2nd package that you need to add in addition to the `bash` package.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create your own custom completions you can look at this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21476506/2649637