# bash completion for teamocil

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I'm trying to define bash auto-completion for [teamocil](http://remiprev.github.com/teamocil/) so that when I type `teamocil <tab>` it should complete with the file names in the folder `~/.teamocil/` without the file extensions. There's an example for `zsh` in the website:

```
compctl -g '~/.teamocil/*(:t:r)' teamocil
```

how can I use this in `bash`?

**Edit:** Influenced by michael_n 's answer I have come up with a one-liner:

```
complete -W "$(teamocil --list)" teamocil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generalized version of another completion script I have that does something similar.  It assumes a generic hypothetical command "flist", using some directory of files defined by FLIST_DIR to complete the command (omitting options).

Modify the following for your program (`teamocil`), change the default dir from `$HOME/flist` to `$HOME/.teamocil`), define your own filters/transformations, etc; and then just source it (e.g., `. ~/bin/completion/bash_completion_flist`), optionally adding it to your existing list of bash completions.

```
# bash_completion_flist: 
#  for some hypothetical command called "flist",
#  generate completions using a directory of files

FLIST_DIR=${FLIST_DIR=:-"$HOME/flist"}

_flist_list_files() {
   ls $FLIST_DIR | sed 's/\..*//'
}

_flist() {
   local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"       
   COMPREPLY=()
   [[ ${cur} != -* ]] \
      && COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(_flist_list_files)" -- ${cur}))
}

complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _flist flist 2>/dev/null \
    || complete -o default -o nospace -F _flist flist
```

Notes:

- it could be shorter, but this is more or less a template for longer, more complicated completions. (Functions are Good.)
- the actual completion command (`complete -o ...`) is a bit of a hack to work across different versions of bash.
- the suffix stripping is over-simplfied if there are "." in the filename, and is left as an exercise for the reader :-) There are multiple ways to do this (sed, awk, etc); the best is via bash-isms  (`base=${filename%.*}`), but the easiest is arguably the simple sed with some assumptions about the filename format.

Answer (score 0):

Bash implements similar idea but another way, so commands and files for zsh won't work in bash. But you may write your own rules for autocompletion. More info:

- [An introduction to bash completion: part 1](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316)
- [An introduction to bash completion: part 2](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/317)
- SO: [How to enable tab-completion of command line switches in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777017/how-to-enable-tab-completion-of-command-line-switches-in-bash)
- SO: [Auto-complete command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690655/auto-complete-command-line-arguments)